# Search for a string and print everything before and after within a range

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have this file:

```
sometext1{
string1
}

sometext2{
string2
string3
}

sometext3{
string4
string5
string6
}
```

I want to search this file for a specific string and print everything before this string up to the opening `{` and everything after this string up to the closing `}`. I tried to achieve this with sed but if I try to print everything in the range `/{/,/string2/` for example sed prints this:

```
sometext1{
string1
}

sometext2{
string2
sometext3{
string4
string5
string6
}
```

If I search for the string "string2" I need the output to be:

```
sometext2{
string2
string3
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, now I found that I need the line numbers of the ouput in the original file to delete them later. I tried changing the command that @mikeserv supplied with no luck, I'm a bit confused with sed's hold function.

Comment: well, geez, rodrigo, you didnt tell anyone that but yourself. it can be done, but it is best done like `grep -n '' <infile | sed ...`. The `sed` commands will need modifying; specifically the `/`address`/` bits that look for `^`top-of-line anchors. So, if you were using my answer you could probably do: `grep -n '' | sed 'H;/{$/h;/^[^:]*:}/x;/{\n.*PATTERN/!d'`. All output lines will be prefixed with the original file's line numbers followed by a colon like `1:sometext1{\n2:string1` and so on. `sed` will filter only what it would filter before, except that each output line opens with  a number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two commands. If you want a command that trims up to the last `.*{$` line in a sequence *(as @don_crissti does with `ed`)* you can do:

```
sed 'H;/{$/h;/^}/x;/{\n.*PATTERN/!d'
```

...which works by appending every line to `H`old space following a `\n`ewline character, overwriting `h`old space for every line that matches `{$`, and  swapping ing `h`old and pattern spaces for every line that matches `^}` - and thereby flushing its buffer.

It only prints lines which match a `{` then a `\n`ewline and then `PATTERN` at some point - and that only ever happens immediately following a buffer swap.

It elides any lines in a series of `{$` matches to the last in the sequence, but you can get all of those inclusive like:

```
sed '/PATTERN.*\n/p;//g;/{$/,/^}/H;//x;D'
```

What it does is swap pattern and `h`old spaces for every `...{$.*^}.*` sequence, appends all lines within the sequence to `H`old space following a `\n`ewline character, and `D`eletes up to the first occurring `\n`ewline character in pattern space for every line cycle before starting again with what remains.

Of course, the only time it ever gets `\n`ewline in pattern space is when an input line matches `^}` - the end of your range - and so when it reruns the script on any other occasion it just pulls in the next input line per usual.

When `PATTERN` is found in the same pattern space as a `\n`ewline, though, it prints the lot before overwriting it with `^}` again *(so it can end the range and flush the buffer)*.

Given this input file *(thanks don)*:

```
sometext1{
string1
}

sometext2{
PATTERN
string3
}

sometext3{
string4
string5
string6
}

Header{
sometext4{
some string

string unknown

here's PATTERN and PATTERN again
and PATTERN too
another string here
}
}
```

The first prints:

```
sometext2{
PATTERN
string3
}
sometext4{
some string

string unknown

here's PATTERN and PATTERN again
and PATTERN too
another string here
}
```

...and the second...

```
sometext2{
PATTERN
string3
}
Header{
sometext4{
some string

string unknown

here's PATTERN and PATTERN again
and PATTERN too
another string here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with `ed`:

```
ed -s filename <<< $'g/PATTERN/?{?,/}/p\nq\n'
```

that is:

```
g/PATTERN/     # mark each line matching PATTERN  
?{?,/}/p       # for each marked line, print all lines from the previous { up to the next }  
q              # quit editor
```

This assumes there's only one line with `PATTERN` between each pair of `{` `}` otherwise you will get duplicate output for each additional line with `PATTERN` inside the same block.
It will work for multiple `{` `}` containing a single line matching `PATTERN` e.g. for a test file with `PATTERN` in two different sections:

```
sometext1{
string1
}

sometext2{
PATTERN
string3
}

sometext3{
string4
string5
string6
}

Header{
sometext4{
some string

string unknown

here's PATTERN again

another string here
}
}
```

running

```
ed -s sample <<< $'g/PATTERN/?{?,/}/p\nq\n'
```

outputs:

```
sometext2{
PATTERN
string3
}
sometext4{
some string

string unknown

here's PATTERN again

another string here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)\{[^}]*PATTERN.*?\}'
```

Or with GNU `grep` provided the input doesn't contain NUL bytes:

```
grep -Poz '.*(?s)\{[^}]*PATTERN.*?\}'
```

Comment: You might want to add some more info, like: `pcregrep -M` might fail if the line groups need more than 16KiB to be stored ( [pcregrep man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pcregrep.1.html) ), and `grep -Poz` will treat the whole file (without NULs) as a single input line (and it might not fit in the available memory).

Answer (score 1):

An alternate take is the following script:

```
sed -n '
  /GROUP_START/,/GROUP_END/{ # define group as lines between these two patterns
    H                        #  append current line to hold-space
    /GROUP_END/{             #  on the last line of the group:
      x                      #   work on group from hold-space
      /PATTERN/{             #   if PATTERN is included in group:
                             #    optionally process the group here e.g. beautify
        s/^\n//p             #    remove first newline and print group
      }
      z;h                    #   effectively: zap hold-space for the next group
    }
  }
'
```

where **GROUP_START** and **GROUP_END** are the patterns that decide where your group begins and ends (in your case: `{$`, `}$`, and **PATTERN** is your criteria for group printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"; FS="[{}]"} {if ($2 ~ /string4/) {print $2}}' t1.txt
string4
string5
string6
```

where:

- `string4` --> string to be matched
- `t1.txt` --> contains the file content mentioned in the query

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.split(:skip-empty, "\n\n"); .put for @a.grep(/string2/);'  file
```

Briefly, Raku's `grep` is your friend. The file is `slurp`ed in (read all at once), splitting on paragraphs (i.e. `"\n\n"`). Empty elements are dropped. Non-empty elements are stored in the `@a` array. This is what the `@a` array looks like before `grep`ping, using `.raku.say for @a;`:

```perl
"sometext1\{\nstring1\n}"
"sometext2\{\nstring2\nstring3\n}"
"sometext3\{\nstring4\nstring5\nstring6\n}"
```

Once in the array, desired elements are `grep`ped through, searching for `string2`. Finally the result is output linewise with the `.put for`... idiom.

Note: the OP does ask for records from the first curly-brace line to the last curly-brace line, however the example is clearly separated by paragraphs. Nevertheless, the Raku code above can be modified to `split` before/after a particular character, with a `<?before ...>` lookahead and/or a `<?after ...>` lookbehind:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.split(:skip-empty, /  \n\n <?before \N* \{ $$> | <?after \N* \} $$>  /); .put for @a.grep(/string2/);'  file
```

Alternatively, the file can simply be `comb`ed through searching for matching elements, taking advantage of Raku's negative custom character class construct `<-[{}]>*`, which is zero-or-more characters not including `{` opening or `}` closing curly-brace:

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/ \N* \{ <-[{}]>* string2 <-[{}]>* \} /);'  file
```

Sample Output (all code examples above):

```
sometext2{
string2
string3
}
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/comb
https://raku.org